# Swift 4 - How To load images using cache?

Tags: swift, image, url, caching, uiimageview

I have UIImageView and I want to download images in cache if exist, I've used extension func.

I have this code but not working:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func loadImageUsingCache (_ urlString : String) {
        let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as AnyObject) {
            self.image = cachedImage as? UIImage
            return
        }
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if data != nil {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!) {
                    imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: urlString as AnyObject)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                        self.image = image
                    })
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain _not working_  . Your code does not compile? Or causes runtime error? If you get error, on which line and what sort of message? Or it runs without any problems, but you get unexpected results? Explain all such things.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating the new NSCache object for each image and not retain it.
You should create object variable instead of local one. It won't work in extension in this case. Also you can try to use URLCache.shared instead.

Answer (score -1):

// It's Perfect Solution //

var imageCache = String: UIImage

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

```
var lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage: String?

func loadImage(with urlString: String) {

    // set image to nil
    self.image = nil

    // set lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage
    lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage = urlString

    // check if image exists in cache
    if let cachedImage = imageCache[urlString] {
        self.image = cachedImage
        return
    }

    // url for image location
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    // fetch contents of URL
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        // handle error
        if let error = error {
            print("Failed to load image with error", error.localizedDescription)
        }

        if self.lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage != url.absoluteString {
            return
        }

        // image data
        guard let imageData = data else { return }

        // create image using image data
        let photoImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

        // set key and value for image cache
        imageCache[url.absoluteString] = photoImage

        // set image
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.image = photoImage
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

}